# What's missing to have this script compare tab delimited csv files?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, reader

I'm writing a python script to compare csv files. However it only works for comma delimited, even if the delimiter is set to \t...

```
d='\t'

for x in range(0, columns):
    with open(mfile, 'rb') as master:       
        with open(cfile, 'rb') as check:
            master_indices = dict((r[x], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master, delimiter=d))) 
            check_reader = csv.reader(check, delimiter=d)

            for row in check_reader:
                index = master_indices.get(row[x])

                if index is not None:
                    T += 1
                    matches += 1
                else:
                    T += 1
```

Edit:

Test case 1...

mfile:

```
a,1
a,2
```

cfile:

```
x,2
x,z
```

with d=','

reads both columns and returns 1 match with T of 4.

Test case 2...

mfile:

```
a    1
a    2
```

cfile:

```
x    2
x    z
```

with d='\t'

reads column 1 returns 0 matches with T of 2.

Edit: Using provided, **working**, and accepted answer:

```
for x in range(0, columns):
    with open(mfile, 'rb') as master:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(master.read(1024))
        master.seek(0)
        master_reader = csv.reader(master, dialect)

        with open(cfile, 'rb') as check:
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(check.read(1024))
            check.seek(0)
            check_reader = csv.reader(check, dialect)

            master_indices = dict((r[x], i) for i, r in enumerate(master_reader)) 

            for row in check_reader:
                index = master_indices.get(row[x])

                if index is not None:
                    T += 1
                    matches += 1
                else:
                    T += 1
```

Comment: You should show us where `d` is set. Also: what does it mean "not working" in your case? Does it throw an error or does it say the files are different when they are identical?

Comment: Sorry, I've added how d is set, either `d='\t'` or `d=','` and test cases with results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the csv.Sniffer to get the dialect of your csv file:

```
with open(mfile, 'rb') as master:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(master.read(1024))
    master.seek(0)
    master_reader = csv.reader(master, dialect)

    with open(cfile, 'rb') as check:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(check.read(1024))
        check.seek(0)
        check_reader = csv.reader(check, dialect)
```